# Creating an array of objects in python without having to append in a loop

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to create an array of object. I am able to do it like this:

```
def MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, number=0):
         self.number=number

my_objects = []

for i in range(100) :
    my_objects.append(MyClass(0))
```

I want, however, to create the array without the loop (because I think for a more complex object the appending can be very time consuming). Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Appending a complex object to a list is exactly as expensive as appending a simple object, since all that is appended is a reference to the object. Variables, lists, function calls, all these things only store and manipulate references. Unlike in, say, C++, if you don't explicitly make a copy of your object, there probably won't be a copy involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
my_objects = [MyClass(0) for _ in range(100)]
```

If you are using Python 2.x, you should also replace [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) with [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange):

```
my_objects = [MyClass(0) for _ in xrange(100)]
```

This is because the latter computes numbers lazily where as the former creates an unnecessary list.

Comment: In this case wouldn't it actually be ok to use `range` since `range` generates a list of items?

Comment: The list of numbers produced by `range` is a separate thing from the list of objects produced by the comprehension.

Comment: Ah... I thought `range` could be taken advantage of once ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
my_objects = [MyClass(0) for i in range(100)]
```

or using repeat

```
from itertools import repeat

my_objects = map(MyClass, repeat(0, 100))
```